# Cant fire button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Well, im trying to do something with javascript and the button is not firing the event, first i tryed to knew how to prevent to posting back, then i used something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requerimentos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Requerimentos,new { id = "Requerimento", @class = "form-control" })
            <input type="button" onclick="acrescenteLista();return false;" value="Adicionar" id="Adicionar" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Requerimentos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <ul id="Requerimentos">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the button should call the acrescentaLista() function that is in my script that is called correctly.
**Here is my script**

```
function acrescenteLista() {
    var texto1 = document.getElementById("Requerimento").value;
    var texto = document.getElementById("Requerimentos");
    console.log(texto);
    console.log(texto2);

}
```

how can i solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You script works properly here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ogtnfk75/4/

```
 function acrescenteLista() {
    var texto1 = document.getElementById("Requerimento").value;
    var texto = document.getElementById("Requerimentos");
    console.log(texto1);
    console.log(texto);

  }
```

Console.log(texto2) ? you dont have that variable in your script